# Why doesn't `npx create-react-app my-app --typescript` give me typescript bo

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is that I ended up with `npx create-react-app my-app --typescript`.  It seems like I still ended up with this javascript looking boilerplate files. Like there is not `.tsx` or `.ts` and I thought for Typescript we should use `import * from as React from 'react'` as opposed to `import React from 'react';`

Can someone help me with this?
[image]

Comment: Yep, I believe all it does extra is install typescript + the related types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript), after initializing a new project, it is the user who must rename their files to use `.tsx` extension:

> Next, rename any file to be a TypeScript file (e.g. src/index.js to src/index.tsx) and restart your development server!